# node.js wait for callback to finish?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I have the following code:

```
            exported.removeWatcher(issueId, user, function(err, result) {
                if (result.statusCode != 204) { // Build a list of failed issues

                } else if (result.statusCode == 204) {

                }
                console.log();
            });
```

I know that using callbacks is one of the strengths of node.js, but for my use-case, I want to wait until i recieve a response from the above callback (i.e not execute the code further unless the callback is fired.) How can i achieve this?

Comment: Is it possible to have further execution of code happen from the callback itself?

Comment: You can use promises;)

Comment: Trying to block the current thread until a condition is met goes against the core design of nodejs. Even if you manage to do this, it would be unadvisable and had the potential to introduce done sis issues.

Comment: You can't. Structure your code to work asynchronously.

Comment: thanks for the comments guys. I was able to do this as advised by GoodDamon, but i will still have to think over the alternate ways to make this work asyncronously. thanks for all the advise.

Comment: generate + co + promise,make the synchronous code(look like),run  asyncronously

Answer (score 0):

You can use [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async). Just install it with npm and "require" it in your code.

For example:

```
async.series([ 
  function(callback) {
    myWaitForThisFunction(callback);
  },
  function(callback) {
    myThenDoThisFunction(callback);
  }
]);
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, upon reading the async.series documentation, it says that if any of the functions encounter an error, then the rest are not called and the main callback is called. For my usecase, i still want to process all functions even if one of the functions had an error. any thoughts on how this can be done using async?

Comment: it says that if any of the functions returns an error not encounters an error. if you handle errors with try and catch blocks, in your catch block you can call the callback function with some other value. For example:  try{ do_something(); callback(result); } catch(error) { console.log(error);callback(myNonErrorVariable); }